# Select all totals for each title query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have many records in a CosmosDB document.  I need to retrieve:
- all records by title
- sum the total for every title.  Some titles have multiple records.
- where the postmate = Y or P

The data appears as:

```
{
    "id": "9999",
    "pm": "Y",
    "total": 100,
    "title": "TESTING",
},

{
    "id": "9999",
    "pm": "Y",
    "total": 100,
    "title": "TESTING3",
},


{
    "id": "9999",
    "pm": "P",
    "total": 100,
    "title": "TESTING",
},
```

In the above data,  I would want the following result:
TESTING, 200
TESTING3, 100

I have tried this:
    select VALUE c.title, sum(c.total)
    FROM c
    where c.pm in ('Y', 'P')

but I receive an error.  I can run this without the sum(c.share).  I tried adding a value but it didn't work.

select VALUE [c.title, c.total]
FROM c
where c.pm in ('Y', 'P')

returns the title and total for each recordset.  I have no idea how to group them.  Will a nested query work similar to:

```
select VALUE sum(c.total) AS TOTALOWED
FROM (select VALUE [c.title, c.total]
FROM c
```

where c.pm in ('Y', 'P'))

I would like to list every title and sum the total field for all records that have a distinct title.